# post build event in Visual Studio failed in Jenkins

Tags: visual-studio-2013, jenkins, msbuild, post-build-event

I have one C# solution with a few projects in it, in visual studio 2013's post build event of each project, I set up script to sign each dll as following:

```
call "$(DevEnvDir)..\Tools\vsvars32.bat" 
signtool sign /f "$(SolutionDir)mycompany.pfx" /p pwd4Pfx "$(TargetPath)"
```

Now I configure auto build for the solution in Jenkins using msbuild.exe

I got the following error:

(PostBuildEvent target) ->

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(4291,5):
>   error MSB3073: The command "call "*Undefined*..\Tools\vsvars32.bat" 
>   [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Myproject\Project1.csproj]
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(4291,5):
>   error MSB3073: signtool sign /f "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Myproject\mycompany.pfx" /p pwd4pfx
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\myproject\project1\bin\Debug\project1.dll"
>   [C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\myproject\project1\project1.csproj]

How to fix the error in Jenkins?  There must be some setting I did wrong. Thanks

Comment: I heck the envvars and call the cmd this way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31568416/1466046

Comment: It is not that likely that you have the $(DevEnvDir) macro set when you don't have VS installed on the machine.  Trying to do this without VS is never not a mistake.