# Visual Studio 2015 - uninstall languages

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to uninstall certain languages from VS 2015?

I installed the community edition but unlike previous versions it didn't prompt me to select which features I wanted to install so I ended up with languages like : VB, F#, and c++ which I'm never going to use.

Answer (score 0):

Removing VB.net is not possible in Visual Studio 2015. You can unselect C++ under `custom` ([opposite from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31568416/1466046)) and in this dialog you can also remove F#. Run `control panel` go to `programs & features`, select the `visual studio 2015 with updates` and click on modify. Here unselect the checkbox for C++ and F#.

The next [VS will have a better installer to remove as much as possible](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/08/22/the-lightweight-visual-studio-15-installer/),but here C#/VB will be also bundled the same time (.net desktop development).

[image]

Comment: I've got the same problem. So is there any way to uninstall at least c++ and f#?

Comment: @eddy see my reply in the other topic. unmark the checkbox entries for C++ and F#

Comment: What do I have to do to display that dialog?

Comment: open ontrol panel->program & features, select VS2015 with updates, click on modify and uncheck the C++,F# entries

Comment: They're already unchecked :S  If they're  not installed why do I see c++ and f# templates? :(

Comment: I have no idea why you see those entries.