# Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 increase max Process Memory (over 2GB)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, windows-8

**On Windows 8**

Is there a way to increase the process Memory limit of 2GB. My script needs 2.5GB RAM to run after I performed garbage collection to the best of my knowledge.

I need to run in 64-bit (not related to largeaddressaware)

Comment: Compile your project as x64 so it can access more memory. The amount of memory available to Vsiual Studio shouldn't matter, unless youre writing an add-in to Visual Studio.

Comment: Project > Properties > Compile tab.  Untick the "Prefer 32-bit" option, you don't prefer it.  Repeat for the Release configuration.  Look around some more, this is supposed to be discoverable.  Press F1 if you see something you don't understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LargeAddressAware Visual Studio 2015 C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565532/largeaddressaware-visual-studio-2015-c-sharp)

Comment: You can use [**archive.org/web/**](http://archive.org/web/) to lookup dead links, in most cases you'll find them. Here's the one you're referring to: http://web.archive.org/web/20151221132808/http://mkwec.de/2010/01/08/make-visual-studio-use-more-than-2-gig-of-memory

Comment: @HansPassant do you want to answer this? Because you solved my problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2017 compiles in 32bit on 64 bit system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49762203/visual-studio-2017-compiles-in-32bit-on-64-bit-system)