# running 'vcvars32' gives error 'vcvars32' is not recognized as an internal or external command in Windows

Tags: visual-studio, htk

I am trying to install [HTK](http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk) toolkit in Windows 8.1. [Here](http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/docs/inst-win.shtml) is the guideline to install. I am following the tutorial in [this](https://github.com/JoFrhwld/FAVE/wiki/HTK-on-Windows) git hub page too. I have already installed Visual Studio 2017.

The issue is when installing HTK, the guideline says **"Ensure that your PATH contains C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\bin"**. What I have **in my system** is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC" and **there is no folder called 'bin'** in this.

Therefore I manually created a folder called 'bin' inside "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC" and continued the installation. But it gives **error when running 'vcvars32'** as '**vcvars32' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

Where can I find that bin folder. If it doesn't exist what shall I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42809603/17034

Comment: Did you check the C/C++ sdk or build tools in the installation program?

Comment: I am not sure. How can I check whether I have installed the build tools

Comment: Now I installed C/C++ SDK also. But still the /bin is not found