# C# VS 2017 - disable DEP feature during build

Tags: c#, linker, visual-studio-2017, dep

As the title says, how do I disable the DEP feature for a specific C# project rather than the whole of the OS? I use Visual Studio 2017

I need to use an old ActiveX Dll within the project, which requires this feature disable otherwise it will throw errors at runtime.

Note I have looked everywhere and followed every google search. My properties/options don't seem to match whats said on the internet (maybe because I'm using VS 2017??)

Thanks

Comment: https://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-xp/disable-turn-off-dep-windows/

Comment: What are the errors? Have you tried using Late Binding? How are you referencing the Active X DLL?

Comment: You have to run Editbin.exe in a post-build event.  Use the /NXCOMPAT:NO and /HIGHENTROPYVA:NO options.  This got complicated in VS2017, workaround [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42809603/17034).

Comment: Thanks that helped

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I fixed it thanks to everyone's help:

1. Make sure to install **VC++ 2017 v141-Toolset (x86,x64)**
2. Add the following to the Post-Build event:

> call "$(DevEnvDir)..\tools\vsdevcmd.bat"
>
> "$(DevEnvDir)....\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\Hostx86\x86\editbin.exe"
> /NXCOMPAT:NO "$(TargetPath)"

There must be a newline between *...vsdevcmd.bat"* and *"$(DevEnvDir...*
Also the toolset version may change *(14.13.26128)* so adjust where necessary.

Comment: I regret a bit showing how to do it both ways.  You *either* use vsdevcmd.bat *or* you use the full path.  Given that these path names turned out not to be stable at all, you really do favor the vsdevcmd.

Comment: still works like a charm in VS19, however the location for vsdevcmd.bat is different in VS19